# regular expression replacement in JavaScript with some part remaining intact

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I need to parse a string that comes like this:

```
-38419-indices-foo-7119-attributes-10073-bar
```

Where there are numbers followed by one or more words all joined by dashes.  I need to get this:

```
[ 
   0 => '38419-indices-foo',
   1 => '7119-attributes',
   2 => '10073-bar',
]
```

I had thought of attempting to replace *only the dash before a number* with a `:` and then using `.split(':')` - how would I do this?  I don't want to replace the other dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Imo, the pattern is straight-forward:

```
\d+\D+
```

To even get rid of the trailing `-`, you could go for

```
(\d+\D+)(?:-|$)
```

Or

```
\d+(?:(?!-\d|$).)+
```

You can see it here:

```js
var myString = "-38419-indices-foo-7119-attributes-10073-bar";
var myRegexp = /(\d+\D+)(?:-|$)/g;
var result = [];
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  // matched text: match[0]
  // match start: match.index
  // capturing group n: match[n]
  result.push(match[1]);
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}

console.log(result);

// alternative 2
let alternative_results = myString.match(/\d+(?:(?!-\d|$).)+/g);
console.log(alternative_results);
```

---

Or a [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/VKsGZ8/1).

Comment: Nice solution. You could forego the capture group with `\d+\D*(?!-)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZ0WdT/2/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks. But no, unfortunately not, see https://regex101.com/r/AZ0WdT/3 (and have a look at the captured groups). The problem is that `\D*` eats up the `-` as well.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: You could use a tempered greedy token technique as in [**`\d+(?:(?!-\d|$).)+`**](https://regex101.com/r/AZ0WdT/4/)

Comment: Ah, yes, the trailing hyphen is not wanted. Then `\d+\D*(?=-|$)` to avoid the capture group.

Comment: I see what I mentioned in my last comment is just what you have except you've captured `\d+\D*`. Why do that rather than just use the match, which is the same as the content of the capture group?

Answer (score 0):

### Logic

lazy matching using quantifier `.*?`

### Regex

`.*?((\d+)\D*)(?!-)`

https://regex101.com/r/WeTzF0/1

### Test string

-38419-indices-foo-7119-attributes-10073-bar-333333-dfdfdfdf-dfdfdfdf-dfdfdfdfdfdf-123232323-dfsdfsfsdfdf

### Matches

[image]

### Further steps

You need to split from the matches and insert into your desired array.